# Why does .parentNode return 'undefined' on the 'this' pointer?

Tags: javascript, function, this

I have set up a custom homepage that links to a few bookmarks like Google or Wikipedia.

The links are set up as `a` elements that contain the specific site's `href`. Within the `a` element, I put a `div` with `class="clickArea"` and `onmouseover="overClickArea('page-description')"`, which displays a short description in some other `div` (that works fine).

Also, it should actually set the content of my own custom search bar (within the site) to the value of the `href` attribute of the parent `a` tag. The search bar is an `input` element.

To get that `href` value, I use `parentNode` and `getAttribute('href')` on the `this` pointer. The `parentNode` function returns `undefined` though.

I am aware of the `this` pointer referring to the element that the function is a method of.
I have unsuccessfully tried to replace `this` with `div` and to pass `this` as a function parameter.

I'd be glad to get that one done, thanks a lot for any help :)

One of the links:

```
<a href="http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hauptseite">
    <div class="clickArea" onmouseover="overClickArea('Wikipedia - The Free Encyclopedia')">
       <img class="icon" src="Icon_Wikipedia.png" alt="Wikipedia" />
       <br>Wikipedia
    </div>
</a>
```

JavaScript function:

```
function overClickArea(descStr){
    document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = descStr;

    var url = this.parentNode.getAttribute('href');
    document.getElementById('searchbar').value = url;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `overClickArea` like this:

```
onmouseover="overClickArea('page-description')"
```

Since you haven't specified a context, it will be called in the context of the default object. In a browser, that is `window`.

You seem to be assuming that it will be the element the `onmouseover` attribute is attached to. It isn't.

`window` doesn't have a `parentNode` property (at least by default).

Inside the event handler function itself (i.e. `onmouseover="this"`), `this` will be that element.

Answer (score 1):

`this`refers to the window object, so it does not have a parent node. Change it

```
 <div class="clickArea" onmouseover="overClickArea(this,'Wikipedia - The Free Encyclopedia')">
```

and :

```
function overClickArea(source, descStr){
    document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = descStr;

    var url = source.parentNode.getAttribute('href');
    document.getElementById('searchbar').value = url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Quentins Answer, to access the element , instead of using `this` in your function ( *which references the function itself* ) you need the `event.target` and that is best passed in from your mouseover handler

```
onmouseover="overClickArea(event,'Wikipedia - The Free Encyclopedia')"
```

Then, in your function accept it and you can get the this you are after

```
function overClickArea(event,descStr){

   event = event || window.event;
   var url = event.target.parentNode.getAttribute('href');
    ....
```

Comment: You don't actually need `event = event || window.event` if you're passing `event` in a handler attribute. The function that old IE creates will not have an `event` parameter defined, so it'll naturally pick up the `window.event` from the global scope. However, you would need `(event.target || event.srcElement).parentNode.get...`, though the `target` doesn't seem to be what OP wants.

Comment: Good Point @cookiemonster - old habits ! I considered deleting this anser as passing `this` from the handler is much better/ shorter - but does no harm to see this way too ( I thought ) Thanks.

Comment: Ahh just spotted your point on the event.srcElement, yes , that is needed and something I missed. thanks.

Comment: Yep, the `event = event || window.event;` was harmless. Just thought I'd mention it. :-)